# How to work with generic type array and generic type class as parameter in constructor?

Tags: scala

I want to convert the following simple java code into scala code. I know `T <: Comparable[T]` will be used for `T extends Comparable`. For generic type array, I have to use either `Manifest` or `ClassManifest` but I could not convert the two constructors for scala code.

```
public class MyClass<T extends Comparable> {

    private static int MAX_SIZE = 40;
    private T[] array;
    private int count = 0;

    public MyClass(Class<T> clazz) {
        this(clazz, MAX_SIZE);
    }

    public MyClass(Class<T> clazz, int size) {
        array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rough sketch of what a Scala class would look like:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class MyClass[T : Ordered : ClassTag](size: Int) {
  val arr: Array[T] = new Array[T](size)

  def this() {
    this(40)
  }
}
```

Because of Scala auxiliary constructor initialization order, you can't access `this` inside the constructor (that is the reason I hard coded `40` instead of settings a max value field). If you want to get around that, you can define a companion object to `MyClass` with an `apply` method which takes no argument:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class MyClass[T : Ordered : ClassTag](size: Int) {
  val arr: Array[T] = new Array[T](size)
}

object MyClass {
  final val maxSize: Int = 40
  def apply[T : Ordered : ClassTag]() = new MyClass[T](maxSize)
}
```

And then utilize it like this:

```
val clz = MyClass[Int]()
```

Comment: `import reflect.ClassTag`

Comment: Thank you so much.